# Angular 5 response header is missing on CORS

Tags: cors, angular5, response-headers

In my angular app, I need to retrieve Location data from the response header.
The server (Nginx) is configured to allow cross origin and to allow/expose location in header. I can see this in the chrome DEV console but in my angular app, I don't see any data for the header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Location, Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Location, Content-Type
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
this.httpClient.post( url, {
        UserName: username,
        Password: password
      }
    )
      .subscribe(
        (res: Response) => {
          console.log(res.headers);
        },
        error => {console.log('Error occured::' + error);
        }
      );
```

console.log(res.headers) returns undefined.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new HttpClient returns only the body by default. Should you want to retrieve anything from the response itself you can use the option observe:

```
  this.httpClient.post(url, {
    UserName: username,
    Password: password
  }, {
    observe: 'response'
  })
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.headers.get('Location');
  }, error => {
    console.log('Error occured::' + error);
  });
```

You were typecasting res to Response so TypeScript didn’t catch your error. It’s better to remove the type as in my example so it is automatically typed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see only 'Content-Type' in  the header. Location  is  missing.

Comment: Could you post all of the headers that are returned by the server for the preflight (OPTIONS) request and the actual request itself?

Comment: I see preflight response header in Network on DEV console. It returns 200. After that it returns actual response header with code 201 which has location in header. But I can't get it in Angular.  I see below in console.                                                                                                      HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
headers

Map(1)
size
:
(...)
__proto__
:
Map
[[Entries]]
Array(1)
lazyInit
null
lazyUpdate
:
null
normalizedNames
Map(1) {"content-type" => "content-type"}
__proto__

Comment: Might be missing something in Nginx server configuration ?

Comment: Yes, your CORS headers are probably incomplete. To check, could you post all of the headers that are returned by the server for the preflight (OPTIONS) request and the actual request itself? Be aware that Access-Control-Expose-Headers should only be returned by the actual request, not by the preflight.

Comment: I found the issue. It's on Nginx configuration. I didn't add comma between two header types on expose header. ;) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK. There were two issues. As @Manduro pointed out, need to add observe in the angular request. Another one is I missed the comma between two header types.

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Need to add 'always' keyword in the location config file